# strip_tags not working properly of ahref

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I am using strip_tags() function to extract the contents of a link (the text part not the link part). The string is obtained from twitter. Unfortunately it returns the same thing.

The code is as follows

```
$a = $cur['source'];
echo strip_tags($a);
```

**Input**

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android">Twitter for Android</a>
```

**Output**

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android">Twitter for Android</a>
```

When I copy pasted the input to a string and tried strip_tags its working perfectly. What could be the reason/?

Comment: what does `var_dump($a)` give?

Comment: try `strip_tags(html_entity_decode($cur['source']));`

Comment: @eis string(91) "<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android">Twitter for Android</a>"

Comment: The probable reason is that your angle brackets were being converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;` html entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to use [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/function.html-entity-decode) because your HTML looked to be HTML, but wasn't (in fact, all html codes were themselves encoded to other html codes).

If you try to `echo htmlentities($cur['source'])`, you'll see

```
&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/download/android&quot;&gt;Twitter for Android&lt;/a&gt;
```

This mean this string can be displayed on a browser without being interpreted as html (as a link in your case). That's very useful if for example, I want to display `<html>` on Stackoverflow without seeing my `<html>` tag interpreted.